# Neo4j : When Query using an index hint , I got Unknown error

Tags: neo4j

I use the exactly query just as http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-using.html says.
My Neo4j Kernel version is
Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 2.0.0-M03

I don't know why?

It's ok for me to run

```
 CREATE (_1 { `name`:"Emil" })
 CREATE (_2:`German` { `name`:"Stefan", `surname`:"Plantikow" })
 CREATE (_3 { `age`:34, `name`:"Peter" })
 CREATE (_4:`Swedish` { `age`:36, `awesome`:true, `name`:"Andres", `surname`:"Taylor" })
 CREATE _1-[:`KNOWS`]->_3
 CREATE _2-[:`KNOWS`]->_4
 CREATE _4-[:`KNOWS`]->_3
```

But I got Unknown error while using

```
match n:Swedish using index n:Swedish(surname) 
where n.surname = 'Taylor' 
return n
```

Comment: You don't have to quote (with backticks) names that are valid identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

If your query explicitly mandates to use an index, you need to make sure that it exists.
So run before querying:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Swedish(surname)
```

Comment: See also the error message in http://console.neo4j.org/r/e7i8dv which goes away if you created the index.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But problem still exist. I run  CREATE INDEX ON :Swedish(surname)  first  and then  The query . Still unknown error

Comment: Are you sure doing the `CREATE INDEX` in a separate statement?

Comment: sorry.. I don't understand what you said .. Do you mean that I should run CREATE INDEX and The query same time ? Just like       CREATE INDEX ON :Swedish(surname)
MATCH n:Swedish 
using index n:Swedish(surname)
where n.surname = 'Taylor' 
return n       I tried but It said "Invalid query

string matching regex `\z' expected but `M' found "

Comment: no, you should run three seperate Cypher statements: 1) create the index: CREATE INDEX ON :Swedish(surname) 2) insert your data, 1st snippet in your questions, 3) query: match n:Swedish using index n:Swedish(surname) where n.surname = 'Taylor' return n. Note that 1) and 2) can be interchanged.

Comment: You can also create the index after the fact, if you are running this in the neo4j-shell or web-ui console you can check the index status with the `schema`command (2.0-M04)